# Postgresql function loop through input arguments and append to hstore

Tags: postgresql, loops, arguments, plpgsql, hstore

I'm wondering if it is possibile in PostgreSQL to loop through all available input parameters of the current function and append these arguments (key=>value) to a hstore variabele.

hstore-key = the name of the given input argument/parameter....

hstore-Value = the value of the given argument...

For example:

```
-- input for call function with input arguments
SELECT append_hstore_from_args ('val1','val22','val333');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION append_hstore_from_args (IN param1 text, IN param2 text, IN param3 text)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE   
new_h hstore;    
BEGIN
-- below is pseudo
for p in all_params
loop 
    new_h := new_h+"$p->name"=>"$p->value";
end loop;

-- at this point the variable new_h (hstore) should contain 
-- '"param1"=>"val1","param2"=>"val22","param3"=>"val333"'

-- call function with hstore argument
perform test.func123(new_h);

RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
```

I've searched, but unfortunately didn't find any hints on how to get this done in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it is a question of how to handle a [variable number of function arguments](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS).

Variadic arguments are accessible inside a function as an array. You can use [FOREACH ... LOOP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

```
create or replace function strings_to_hstore(args variadic text[])
returns hstore language plpgsql as $$
declare
    idx int = 0;
    str text;
    hst hstore;
    res hstore = '';
begin
    foreach str in array args loop
        idx:= idx+ 1;
        execute format($f$select 'param%s=>%s'$f$, idx, str) into hst;
        res:= res|| hst;
    end loop;
    return res;
end $$;

select strings_to_hstore('one', 'two');

            strings_to_hstore         
----------------------------------
 "param1"=>"one", "param2"=>"two"
(1 row)

select strings_to_hstore('red', 'green', 'blue');

                  strings_to_hstore                   
------------------------------------------------------
 "param1"=>"red", "param2"=>"green", "param3"=>"blue"
(1 row)
```

If you wanted to define hstore keys in the argument list:

```
create or replace function strings_with_keys_to_hstore(args variadic text[])
returns hstore language plpgsql as $$
declare
    idx int = 0;
    key text;
    str text;
    hst hstore;
    res hstore = '';
begin
    foreach str in array args loop
        idx:= idx+ 1;
        if idx & 1 then
            key:= str;
        else
            execute format($f$select '%s=>%s'$f$, key, str) into hst;
            res:= res|| hst;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return res;
end $$;

select strings_with_keys_to_hstore('key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2');

  strings_with_keys_to_hstore   
--------------------------------
 "key1"=>"val1", "key2"=>"val2"
(1 row)
```

Note, that there are [standard hstore functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html): `hstore(text[])` and `hstore(text[], text[])`.

Comment: Hi Klin,Many Thanks for your response, I really like your feedback and there are some parts which I can certainly use. On the other hand I really mean a function with several loose arguments (not 1 array) like in the example. This is the situation at the moment. So a function with lets say 3 input arguments....which should be all included into 1 hstore variabele and passed on to a 2nd functions which is expecting 1 input hstore argument.

Comment: Should the hstore keys be simply `param1, param2, param3` or do you want to set their names dynamically?